# php html and text email, force text version to send

Tags: php

is there a way to force test the text version of my email template. All my email accounts view HTML, I need to make sure the text version displays properly.

```
    $mime_boundary = 'Multipart_Boundary_x'.md5(time()).'x';        
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=" .$mime_boundary. "\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . "\r\n";

    $text_content = file_get_contents('emails/welcome_txt.tpl');
    $html_content = file_get_contents('emails/welcome.tpl');

    $body = "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
    $body.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=charset=us-ascii\n";
    $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $body.= $text_content;
    $body.= "\n\n";
    $body.= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

    $body.= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
    $body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-\n";
    $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $body.= $html_content;
    $body.= "\n\n";
    $body.= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    $body = str_replace("{Username}",$en['user'],$html_content);
    mail($en['email'], $subject, $body, $headers, '-f' . $returnpath);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just comment out the $body section where you have the boundary and include the html text?  The other way would be to configure your email client and specify it to receive only text and not html.

Comment: FYI, http://litmus.com/email-previews shows you previews of your emails as seen in many clients. I thought you might find it handy.

Comment: @TimWithers I thought about that but I want to see a full process to make sure there is no error or hiccups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this without changing your code is, with your Email client, view the original email.

For example, with Gmail you can go to the top right arrow (next to reply), and select "Message Text Garbled"  or "Show original"